# I want my controlleradvice to always produce JSON when handling exceptions

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have centralized my exception handling for my rest service into a neat ControllerAdvice.

I am returning regular transfer-objects, in the hope of my cool mapping-jackson-converter will convert it into JSON for the end client.

Now here's the thing. If i don't set the accept-header to "Application/JSON", i don't get the converted JSON, i get some default HTML instead, in my tests seemingly generated by Jetty. I have to admit i'm not sure why, but i guess it's some default Spring resolver that comes into effect.

This got me thinking. Clients who call my rest URL's should know that i return JSON, so i would like my service to always return json regardless.

Is there some way to configure the ReqeustMappingHandlerAdapter to always produce JSON?

my current config:

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <beans:property name="messageConverters">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref bean="jsonConverter"/>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<!-- Instantiation of the converter  in order to configure it -->
<beans:bean id="jsonConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
    <!--beans:property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json"/-->
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: can you post your method exception handler definition?

Comment: I just have a @controlleradvice class, like in this example http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-from-the-trenches-adding-validation-to-a-rest-api/

Comment: does your method have @ResponseBody annotation?

Comment: Yes indeed. As i mentioned, it works if i set the accept-header to json, if i remove it it defaults to some generated HTML. I would like it to just produce JSON, always.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this answers your question, but you could set the default content type in your Spring configuration to JSON (it defaults to HTML without the Accept header in Spring MVC). Here is a sample configuration:

```
<bean id="contentNegotiationManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json" />
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager" />
```

Source:

http://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc

Comment: Thanks. thats not a bad idea, but wont work for my application since i have both JSON and Html clients.